# understanding a specific Extends Classes in Javascript from my job

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to understand why someone in my system did this. In the first JS code, he do a require to commonService, after, create a class PedidoService extends CommonService, defining async find(req, res) again, once that async find(req, res) is defined in CommonService class.

```
const CommonService = require('./commonService');
class PedidoService extends CommonService {
constructor() {
    super(new PedidoBO());
}
async find(req, res) {
    try {
        let params = req.swagger.params;
        let result = await this._contextBO.findPedidos(params)
        if (result.results === null) {
            result.results = [];
        }
        Response.responseAPI.success(res, result, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof ErroException) {
            Response.responseAPI.error(res, HttpStatusCode.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, err.message, true);
        }
        else {
            Response.responseAPI.error(res, HttpStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err.message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the commonService.js:

```
class CommonService {
constructor(contextBO) {
    this._contextBO = contextBO;
}
async find(req, res) {
    try {
        let params = req.swagger.params;
        let result = await this._contextBO.find(params);
        if(result.results === null) {
            result.results = [];
        }
        Response.responseAPI.success(res, result, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof ErroException) {
            Response.responseAPI.error(res, HttpStatusCode.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, err.message, true);
        } 
        else {
            Response.responseAPI.error(res, HttpStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the copied async function PedidoService. Image you have an instance of *PedidoService*. You could always call the function with `PedidoService.find(req, res);` because *PedidoService* extends *CommonService*.

Comment: Thanks my friend!

Comment: Happy to hear that it help you! Please close this question by marking this answer as the one that solved your problem with the check symbol :)